# Troubleshooting FB ads creation in SwiftUI app with updated FB SDK

Tags: swift, swiftui, fbsdk

How do you correctly implement the Facebook SDK in a swiftUI app? I've tried all the official documentation to the letter, and events weren't sending to the events manager (later I discovered without the ATT popup being accepted in both our app & the Facebook mobile app, events wouldn't register in events manager).

Now that I have added the ATT pop-up, events are correctly sending, as seen in the debug logs, but they're only viewable in the overview section of the events manager, not the graphs. I also can't create FB ads, as it's saying update from FB v 0.0.1 (a version that doesn't even exist) and tells me to upgrade to the most current version with SPM, which is what has been done in the initial place.

The things I have tried: ["ATT Code, along with revenuecat fb ads integration code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjoJ4.png) this is the ATT implementation (appears to be working fine, but just for greater clarity incase its linked in a way I haven't seen).

Then inside the info.plist, the correct FB-ID, Token, FB-app name have been added. And lastly as it's a swiftUI app, I've created an app delegate with the following code: [App delegate code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtRc6.png)

I'm expecting FB to at least recognise the SDK version, but it says I need to update from v 0.0.1